# angular2 how to bundle a UMD module without ng2 dependencies

Tags: angular, rollupjs

I'm trying to use rollup to bundle an ng2 module using UMD, but the ng2 dependencies are not being excluded as I intended:

**Rollup Options:**

```
{
    format: "umd",
    moduleName: "mymodule",
    dest: "dist/app.bundle.umd.js",
    sourceMap: true
}
```

**Node Resolve Plugin** (rollup-plugin-node-resolve)

```
nodeResolve({
    jsnext: true,
    module: true,
    skip: [
        "@angular/common",
        "@angular/compiler",
        "@angular/compiler-cli",
        "@angular/core",
        "@angular/forms",
        "@angular/http",
        "@angular/platform-browser",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
        "@angular/platform-server",
        'rxjs'
    ]
}),
```

The output of this is:

```
exports.AppModule = __decorate([
_angular_core.NgModule({
    imports: [
        _angular_platformBrowser.BrowserModule,
        _angular_http.HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [AppComponent]
})], exports.AppModule);
```

By skipping ng2 dependencies, it seems Rollup created global dependencies, where `_angular_core`, `_angular_http` and `_angular_platformBrowser` need to be defined globally.

I want the dependencies to be preserved but not as global dependencies. For example, this is what `tsc` produces, when targeting `umd`:

```
"use strict";
var core_1 = require("@angular/core");
var app_component_1 = require("./app.component");
var platform_browser_1 = require("@angular/platform-browser");
var http_1 = require("@angular/http");
var AppModule = (function () {
    function AppModule() {
    }
    return AppModule;
}());
AppModule = __decorate([
    core_1.NgModule({
        imports: [
            platform_browser_1.BrowserModule,
            http_1.HttpModule
        ],
        declarations: [app_component_1.AppComponent],
        providers: [],
        bootstrap: [app_component_1.AppComponent],
        exports: [app_component_1.AppComponent]
    })
], AppModule);
exports.AppModule = AppModule;
```

You can see that the `require` statements are embedded in the UMD module (this is what I'm trying to achieve), rather than having global dependencies defined.

I am probably not using rollup correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps Rollup is the wrong tool for this, is there a better tool someone can recommend?  I am using gulp for my build.

Answer (score 2):

I got rollup working.

Target es6 modules for the build, then use rollup: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Migrating-from-Esperanto

Esperanto also worked and led me to the solution.  Although it is deprecated, it does produce cleaner, more readable code: https://www.npmjs.com/package/esperanto

### Step 1: Compile to es6 modules

```
tsc --module es6
```

### Step 2: Use rollup to create UMD bundle

```
const pkg = require('./package.json')
const rollup = require('rollup');

gulp.task('rollup:module', function() {
  rollup.rollup({
    // no more `base` – internal module paths
    // should be relative
    entry: pkg.main
  }).then( function ( bundle ) {
    bundle.write({
      // you can do `var umd = bundle.generate({...})
      // instead, and write the file yourself if
      // you prefer
      dest: `${pkg.name}.bundle.umd.js`,

      // use this instead of `toUmd`
      format: 'umd',

      // this is equivalent to `strict: true` -
      // optional, will be auto-detected
      exports: 'named',

      // `name` -> `moduleName`
      moduleName: pkg.name,

      // `names` -> `globals`
      globals: {
        'other-lib': 'otherLib'
      }
    });
  });
```

The nice thing about rollup is that it does tree shaking for smaller, optimized bundles. You can also easily target multiple bundle formats:

```
//UMD
bundle.write({
  dest: `dist/${pkg.name}.bundle.umd.js`,
  format: 'umd',
  exports: 'named',
  moduleName: pkg.name,
  globals: {
  }
});

//CommonJS
bundle.write({
  dest: `dist/${pkg.name}.bundle.cjs.js`,
  format: 'cjs',
  exports: 'named',
  moduleName: pkg.name,
  globals: {
  }
});

//AMD
bundle.write({
  dest: `dist/${pkg.name}.bundle.amd.js`,
  format: 'amd',
  exports: 'named',
  moduleName: pkg.name,
  globals: {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool called [typescript-library-bundler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-library-bundler) that was very useful.

I hope that helps someone else.

Comment: I've since created a template: https://github.com/angular-patterns/ng-module-template.git

Comment: That's nice but that tool supports all styles (CSS, Sass, Less) and minifies them too. Very handy :)